# page views and page like count by date wise for the particular page php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to store views and like counts for the particular page .

im using page url is the unique key (index.php),

in my table i have the following columns

common table

```
id   |   page name    |  views    |    likes     |   timestamp  
 1   |   index.php    |    5      |      3       |   6-2-2014   
 2   |   abount.php   |   15      |     77       |   6-2-2014
```

for views table

```
id   |   page name    |  date    |   ip   
 1   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.1
 2   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.2
 3   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.3
 4   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.4
 5   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.5
```

for like table

```
id   |   page name    |  date    |   ip   
 1   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.1
 2   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.2
 3   |   index.php    | 6-2-2014 | 127.0.0.3
```

what im did here means , every time i insert new record in count table i increase the count for particular page in the common table ,

1) Here i allowed only one time to like particular page from one IP. 
2) i need to know how i get daily views and likes reports .

I know i have maintaining complicated tables , any simplification for this approach

**sorry for my english**

Comment: View table and like table should have foreignKey "page_id" from common table.And "page name" field should be removed

Comment: Yes, do as @nedstark says or the winter will come! Always use foreign keys instead of varchar where possible. You are duplicating the data unnecessarily and losing lot's of space in your database, not to mention the selects are way slower.

Comment: No, you keep things in their separate boxes. You don't keep the milk and eggs in the same bowl just because MAYBE someday you will bake the cake.

Answer (score 0):

The comments about creating a foreign key for the page_id are good and you should look at those.  However, your question was about how to get daily summary reports.

This will give you daily views (the same will apply for likes):

```
SELECT page_name, date, COUNT(ip) as viewcount
FROM views
GROUP BY page_name, date
ORDER BY page_name, date  -- you can select any ordering...
```